# Why is each rendering counted 2 times instead of 1 for useRef and Set per component?

Tags: react-hooks

Why is each rendered component the count and store appended 2 instead of 1 in the counter with useRef and in the Set for the callback functions for each component?

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

const store = new Set();
let count = 0;

export function Forms() {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const countRef = useRef(++count);

  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(value);
  }

  store.add(submit);
  console.log(`Created functions: ${store.size}
  Counter useRef: ${countRef.current}`);

  return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
      </form>
  );
}

function App () {
  return (
    <>
      <Forms />
      <Forms />
      <Forms />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYYkG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because you are probably using [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) in react(when creating app with create-react-app the default is strict mode).

when wrapping your app with `StrictMode` each render will cause another render.

go to your index.js and remove the wrapping `StrictMode` over your app.

Comment: And why does create-react-app use strict mode by default? Is it best practice or is it just some feature for better development that shouldn't be in deployment?

Comment: exactly. it just some feature for better development that shouldn't be in deployment. if this solves your problem don't forget to accept my answer.